# Oracle sql developer command java commandline

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

Our system administrator has disabled starting non-approved programs from the commandline and I am not allowed to start sqldeveloper.exe, but I am allowed to start java. Does anyone therefore know what the commandline syntax is to start java with sqldeveloper as the application ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  Hows does you company expect you to get your work done if you can't load the tools through normal processes.

Comment: Why do you need to start it from the command line - or can't you launch it from Windows Explorer either?

Comment: A simple way to start it is to double-click SQL Developer icon located on a Desktop; why wouldn't you try it?

Comment: I cannot start Sql developer because it is not allowed, but I can start another tool from Allround Automation

Comment: The company which is hiring me has a very strict policy, only certain programs are allowed to run. If you need a program, you need to request installation of it and if the request is approved, it will be installed by a custom tool. You cannot install software yourself. For Oracle development, the tool from Allround automation is chosen, which I very much dislike. Since I am not allowed to install Toad or Oracle SQL Developer, but Java is allowed, I should be able to surpass launching sql-developer and just start it from the Java-commandline, right ?

Comment: Well, reading what you've said, you should STOP doing that. If company policy is that strict, your best option (if you don't want to get fired) is to convince them that (free, Oracle developer) SQL Developer suits your needs better than Allround automation's (PL/SQL Developer, I presume). If they *catch* you using software you aren't supposed to, huh, imagine the rest yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible not recommended but possible since as you say it's a java program. The only things that will be lost is file associations with the base OS. Which means double-click a .sql file will not open sqldev.

The cmd line is a not simple and running on linux/osx the sqldeveloper shell script you can get it.

```
bash -x sqldeveloper
```

Then you'll see the java command in the console which will be something like this which is my mac.

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar -Djdeveloper.system_http_proxy=DIRECT -Djdeveloper.system_http_non_proxy_hosts= -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:CompileCommand=quiet -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dnetbeans.home=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/ -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi -Dide.cluster.dirs=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/fcpbridge/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/ide/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/../ -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1 -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false -Dosgi.noShutdown=true '-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*' -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app -Dosgi.locking=none -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=../../ide/bin/swing-thread-violations.conf -Xms128M -Xmx800M -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su -Dide.update.usage.servers=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging-debug.conf -Dsqldev.debug=true -Dsqldev.cloud=true -Dsqldev.onsd=true -Dsqldev.onsdDDL=true -ea -Dosgi.clean=true -Dsqldev.debugbuild=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dprism.order=sw -Dprism.verbose=true -Dcom.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name=SQL_Developer -Dcom.apple.mrj.application.growbox.intrudes=false -Dcom.apple.macos.smallTabs=true -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true '-Xdock:name=Oracle SQL Developer' -Xdock:icon=SQLDeveloperIcons.icns '-Dide.conf="/Users/klrice/workspace/raptor_trunk/ide/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf"' '-Duser.conf="/Users/klrice/.sqldeveloper/17.4.0/product.conf"' '-Dtool.user.conf="/Users/klrice/.sqldeveloper/17.4.0/sqldeveloper.conf"' '-Dide.startingcwd="/Users/klrice/workspace/raptor_trunk/ide/sqldeveloper/bin"' -Xbootclasspath/p:../../ide/bin/../../rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar -classpath ../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/fcpboot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/xml-factory.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher
```